# Android Unit Test: Mockk io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito, mockk

I have a simple function inside my repository class, that function will parse a static response from the asset and return the result. tried to write a unit test of that function but somehow my test is failing. giving code snippet below.

function from repo:

```
override suspend fun fetchTasks(): ApiResponse<TaskListData> {

        val parsedResponse = context.parseJsonFile("tasks.json")
        val result = parsedResponse?.fromJson<TaskListData>()

        response =
            if (result != null) ApiResponse.Success(result)
            else ApiResponse.Failed(Throwable("Response Parsing Failed"))

        return response
}
```

My test function:

```
    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private val context: Context = mockk<Context>(relaxed = true)

    // Create an instance of the class being tested
    private val fetchTasksRepositoryImpl = FetchTasksRepositoryImpl(context)
    

    @Test
    fun `fetchTasks returns expected response`() = runTest {
        // given
        val testParsedResponse = "Test Response"
        val fileName = "tasks.json"
        every { context.parseJsonFile(fileName) } returns testParsedResponse
        every { context.assets.open(fileName) } returns testParsedResponse.byteInputStream()
        every { testParsedResponse.fromJson<TaskListData>() } returns TaskListData(
            listOf()
        )

        
        val actualResponse = fetchTasksRepositoryImpl.fetchTasks()

        // Assert that the actual response is equal to the mock response
        assertTrue(actualResponse is ApiResponse.Success)

    }
```

json parsing function:

```
fun Context.parseJsonFile(fileName: String): String? {
    return try {
        val inputStream: InputStream = this.assets.open(fileName)
        val size: Int = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer)
        inputStream.close()
        String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8)
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```

Error currently I'm getting

```
Reported exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "<local2>" is null
    at ch.qos.logback.core.android.AndroidContextUtil.getMountedExternalStorageDirectoryPath(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.android.AndroidContextUtil.setupProperties(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at io.mockk.impl.log.JvmLogging.slf4jOrJulLogging(JvmLogging.kt:10)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<clinit>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:160)



io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.checkMissingCalls(StubbingState.kt:14)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.recordingDone(StubbingState.kt:8)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:47)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:60)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at app//io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:92)
    at app//io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:104)
```

Correct me, what I'm currently doing wrong! possible best solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This function `testParsedResponse.fromJson<TaskListData>()` has never been called.

The `fromJson<TaskListData>()` you call in the repository is not the one you call in the test.

You mock the `fromJson` with a variable in your test function, meanwhile a variable in the repository is the different one.

You should make a class to wrap the fromJson function then you can use the function using the class object to insert in your test and call it in your repository.

Example:

```
class Parser {
    companion object {
       fun <T> fromJson(input: String) : T {
          val data = yourDataProcess()
          return data
       }
    }
 }
```

Then in your test

```
every { Parser.fromJson(responser) } returns TaskListData(listOf())
```